# Vector Drawable with Gradient color not suğğorting below API 24

Tags: android, vector, gradient, drawable, android-drawable

Vector drawable of image contains Gradient colors, which are not showing in imageview for below API version of 24, i am using Android-Studio 3.1

Comment: Hi flair (cool username). On StackOverflow this is considered a very incomplete question. The reason is that a minimum of context is required to be given by the quthor. You should add more details on where you're stuck, explain the problem so that other people can understand and possibly show some code where the problem happens.
I would recommend you to spend some time reading through the Asking Guidelines.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have this in module's build.gradle:

   `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`
2. If you use androidX, use this for ImageView in xml:

   `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView ... />`
3. Set image like this:

   `app:srcCompat="@drawable/image"`
   where app namespace is:     `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`